# Why does this document add empty pages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, for-loop

I have this document and it adds ONE empty page at the beginning and TWO empty pages at the end - why is that and how can I get rid of those?

So, instead of only 2 pages, I end up with 5!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20.0mm, paperwidth=50.0mm, layoutheight=20.0mm, layoutwidth=50.0mm, layoutvoffset=0mm,  layouthoffset=0mm, margin=0pt, includeheadfoot, showframe=false, showcrop=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[first=1, last=2147483647, seed=28112018, counter=serialnumber]{lcg}
\newcounter{numpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mypic}[2]{
    \rand
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node (thispage) [shape=rectangle, fill=lightgray, minimum height=\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth, anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {};
        \node[anchor=south] at (thispage.center) {\tiny bg picture here};  %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{dummy.png}};
        \node at (thispage.center) {\decimal{#2} -- \padzeroes[10]{\decimal{#1}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
}

\begin{document}
%\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty} % won't do much
\forloop{numpages}{1}{\value{numpages} < 3}{\mypic{serialnumber}{numpages}}

%\forloop{numpages}{1}{\value{numpages} < 11}{\mypic{serialnumber}{numpages}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: includeheadfoot is probably not a good idea with margin=0pt.  There is no place for the header and footer to go.

Comment: @John: THANKS! That's what I get for copying code I don't exactly know what it does!

Comment: @JohnKormylo, please post your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra pages were due to unprintable headers and footers.  Don't forget to run this twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20.0mm, paperwidth=50.0mm, layoutheight=20.0mm, layoutwidth=50.0mm, layoutvoffset=0mm,  layouthoffset=0mm, margin=0pt, noheadfoot, showframe=false, showcrop=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[first=1, last=2147483647, seed=28112018, counter=serialnumber]{lcg}
\newcounter{numpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mypic}[2]{
    \rand
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node (thispage) [shape=rectangle, fill=lightgray, minimum height=\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth, anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {};
        \node[anchor=south] at (thispage.center) {\tiny bg picture here};  %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{dummy.png}};
        \node at (thispage.center) {\decimal{#2} -- \padzeroes[10]{\decimal{#1}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
}

\begin{document}
%\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty} % won't do much
\forloop{numpages}{1}{\value{numpages} < 3}{\mypic{serialnumber}{numpages}}

%\forloop{numpages}{1}{\value{numpages} < 11}{\mypic{serialnumber}{numpages}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right! I need to run this twice - because of the `lcg`.
Now I can finish my little "makeMoney": https://github.com/foreachthing/makeMoney

Answer (score 4):

With `includeheadfoot`, the textheight is reduced to make room for them, so your pictures become too big to fit in a page and the break point at the top of the page before the picture is used.

It also doesn't make much sense to use `layout...` options, as you're specifying the same page width and height.

Be also careful about unprotected spaces in your macros.

Did you consider using `standalone`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=20.0mm,
  paperwidth=50.0mm,
  margin=0pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[first=1, last=2147483647, seed=28112018, counter=serialnumber]{lcg}
\newcounter{numpages}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mypic}[2]{% <--- Here
  \rand
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node (thispage) [
      shape=rectangle,
      fill=lightgray,
      minimum height=\paperheight,
      minimum width=\paperwidth,
      anchor=south west
    ] at (current page.south west) {};
    \node[anchor=south] at (thispage.center) {\tiny bg picture here};
    %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{dummy.png}};
    \node at (thispage.center) {\decimal{#2} -- \padzeroes[10]{\decimal{#1}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}% <--- Here
    \newpage
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\forloop{numpages}{1}{\value{numpages} < 3}{\mypic{serialnumber}{numpages}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thansk, egreg. Yes, I did consider `standalone`. But I wanted to make 100% sure, that my page has THIS size and I can scale the image to fit the paper.